# Web view in XML lying under main bar

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I am building an app that has a WebView configured in an xml (fragment_recent_news) driven by the file (Recent News), While the webview is configured to meet the main bar in the xml (see picture), the webview actually goes further up under the main bar than it should, as though it is not following the relative layout guidelines. What am I doing wrong?

fragment_recent_news(xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.hardingsoftware.hrcfitness.RecentNews">


<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

RecentNews:

```
package com.hardingsoftware.hrcfitness;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class RecentNews extends Fragment {

    WebView webView;

    //final static String myBlogAddr = "http://www.hrcfitness.com/recent-news/";
    //String myUrl;


    public RecentNews() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recent_news, container, false);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://hrcfitness.com");
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        return rootView;

    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

[image]

Styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.hardingsoftware.hrcfitness;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set the fragment initially

   HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_1) {
       HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_2) {
    MembershipCard fragment = new MembershipCard();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_3) {
        RecentNews fragment = new RecentNews();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Android Manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

App_bar_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?    attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: check your styles, add the Activity that uses this fragment. That is where the problem is, your stiles must have been overridden grammatically somewhere.

Comment: What should I look for in my styles?

Comment: can you add the style and the activity class?

Comment: added. Any ideas? Also just added MainAcitivity class

Comment: @Jon one last place to look at, Can you put the Activity declaration in the Manifest file?

Comment: I added it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the

`android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` from your Manifest file. It should work.

Edit:

i did not know that you are using a `CoordinatorLayout`

Add the `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` back and put

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to the following component as below.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container" 
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

component.

Comment: It now crashes on launch and throws "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hardingsoftware.hrcfitness/com.hardingsoftware.hrcfitness.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead."

Comment: I don't believe I have a toolbar... what am I looking for? Really appreciate the help by the way.

Comment: did you add a part of your activity_main.xml. or the complete code, because there is got to be one, because you have toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
in your activity

Comment: no that's just carried over from another example integrating webview. Is there anything I can change toolbar to to avoid this issue?

Comment: actually I think I do have a toolbar, which integrates my navigation drawer. Is there anything I can do to replace it?

Comment: That is where the issue is if you add that xml part, I can tell you how to fix it

Comment: added app_bar_main.xml.

Comment: Oh my god it worked... I could kiss you right now! Thanks!

Comment: :D I have felt the same way in SO. Good luck and thanks for the payment ;)